# "In order to provide (the) necessary and adequate protection for their employees" - is definite article necessary?

Tags: definite-article

> Employers should ensure the safety of their employees who are sent
>   abroad on assignment. In order to provide **(the)** necessary and
>   adequate protection for their employees, employers should provide
>   executive buy-in.

In this instance, how would you decide to use it or not?

Comment: By adding *the* you're explicitly saying which *protection* is spoken about.

Comment: So since I said the protection would be executive buy-in, then I would have to add "the". Correct?

Comment: "executive buy-in" is just the prerequisite, it doesn't change the previous phrase. "protection" as generally used is non-specific, so I would leave out the "the". However, you could say "In order to provide *for the* necessary and adequate protection for their employees." if you really want to get "the" in there.

Comment: It works better without the *the*, and it sounds better without *their* in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this variation:

> In order to provide (*the?*) necessary ingredients for their children's growth, parents should provide organic food.

I'd say "the" is unnecessary in this statement (regardless of whether you consider it true or not...).

**Necessary ingredients/protection** are very general, and there may be other requirements besides **organic food/executive buy/in**; these are probably only some of the requirements, so "the" is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying "the" would mean you are referring back to a specific "necessary and adequate protection for their employees" discussed or implied by earlier or observation.

Did previous sentences talk about such a need?  Is the need obvious in the context that this is presented?  If so, and if "executive buy-in" would fill that particular need previously mentioned, then use the article.  Otherwise you should not.